# Provisioning EMR nodes with custom files

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-emr, nutch

I'm trying to run jar with Apache Nutch dependency on AWS EMR Hadoop cluster. The problem is that Nutch can't find plugin classes (I'm specifying plugins location with `-Dplugin.folders`).
I tested this option locally and it's working fine: `java -cp app.jar -Dplugin.folders=./nutch-plugins`.

I'm getting this error:

```
19/07/24 15:42:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1563980669003_0005_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: x point org.apache.nutch.net.URLNormalizer not found.
        at org.apache.nutch.net.URLNormalizers.<init>(URLNormalizers.java:146)
        at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector$InjectMapper.setup(Injector.java:139)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:796)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:342)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

I tried to copy plugins to `/tmp` folder (just a guess that it's a shared folder) - didn't help:

```sh
hadoop jar app.jar -Dplugin.folders=/tmp/nutch-plugins
```

Then I tried to copy it to HDFS - didn't help:

```sh
hadoop fs -cp file:///tmp/nutch-plugins hdfs:///tmp/
hadoop jar app.jar -Dplugin.folders=hdfs:///tmp/nutch-plugins
```

and tried to upload it to S3 bucket - didn't help:

```sh
hadoop fs -cp file:///tmp/nutch-plugins s3a:///mybucket/
hadoop jar app.jar -Dplugin.folders=s3a:///mybucket/nutch-plugins
```

How I can provision Hadoop nodes with Nutch plugins? All that I need is to copy plugin files somewhere to access it from any node in the cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to provision all nodes with needed files using EMR [bootstrap actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-plan-bootstrap.html), so I created a script to copy `nutch-plugins` from S3 bucket to `/tmp/nutch-plugins` directory:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://mybucket/nutch-plugins/ /tmp/nutch-plugins/
```

then uploaded this script to S3 bucket,
and added "custom bootstrap action" while configuring the cluster. It can be added via AWS web console (EMR advanced mode) or with CLI param:

```sh
aws emr create-cluster \
  # ... \
  --bootstrap-actions Path="s3://mybucket/bootstrap.sh"
```

After these steps any node can access plugin files at `/tmp/nutch-plugins`:

```sh
hadoop jar app.jar -Dplugin.folders=/tmp/nutch-plugins
```

Answer (score 2):

In distributed mode (in a Hadoop cluster) the plugins are contained in the job file (`runtime/deploy/apache-nutch-1.x.job`):

1. start with the source package or the Nutch source code cloned from git
2. adapt the configuration in `conf/` - note: also configuration files are shipped in the job file
3. build Nutch (`ant runtime`)
4. run `runtime/deploy/bin/nutch` or `runtime/deploy/bin/crawl`: `hadoop jar <jobfile>` is called to launch the Nutch jobs, so the executable `hadoop` must be on PATH.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It would be helpful if I run just Nutch itself, but I'm running custom jar which is using Nutch classes as a dependency, so I can't deploy my app same way as Nutch